# Linear algebra package over the integers

Tags: optimization, math, linear-algebra, scientific-computing, mathematical-optimization

I've recently ran into the following problem. Given a list of vectors (here I mean tuple) all with integer entries, is there a package (language isn't too much an issue, the faster the better, so I guess C) to very quickly determine when another integer vector is in the span of the original list? I need to do this arithmetic over the integers (no division). I'm sure there is one, but wanted to circumvent the lengthy literature review.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `mathnf` function in [PARI](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) to compute the [Hermite normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_normal_form) of the matrix containing your spanning vectors as columns.  The columns of the HNF matrix span the same lattice, and it is trivial to check if a vector is in this lattice.  There are many more libraries able to calculate the HNF -- Google is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

[CVXOPT](http://abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/) may be an option. In particular, look at this function:

```
cvxopt.glpk.ilp = ilp(...)  
Solves a mixed integer linear program using GLPK.

(status, x) = ilp(c, G, h, A, b, I, B)

PURPOSE
Solves the mixed integer linear programming problem

minimize    c'*x
subject to  G*x <= h
            A*x = b
            x[I] are all integer
            x[B] are all binary
```

Look at this post also: [binary linear programming solver in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326067/binary-linear-programming-solver-in-python/3326755#3326755)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [LinBox](http://www.linalg.org/) is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Does LINPACK have anything?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINPACK

We used to use it a lot in my vector/supercomputer days, and there are usually hardware specific versions.

Comment: The issue is that I need this to use only integral arithmetic not rational. I'm not sure that LINPACK can guarantee that the equation for membership only has integer coefficients.

Comment: @Stev Thanks for verifying that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

The best libraries I know of for this are:

Pari (not GP, but the Pari library itself): http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/

NTL (C++): http://www.shoup.net/ntl/

IML: http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~astorjoh/iml.html

We are starting to add this sort of functionality in flint2 (in particular in the fmpz_mat module):

https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/flint2

The aim of flint is make it absolutely as fast as possible, though the matrix stuff is still heavily under development.