# Python linprog to maximise objective function

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, linear-programming

It has been a while since I have done this so I am a bit rusty, but equation is:

```
max t(C)*x
s.t. Ax <=b
```

And I have my **A** matrix of constraints which is (1448x1359) :

```
[[ 1.  1.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]

 ..., 


 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  1.  1.  1.]]
```

Then I have my binding **b** (1448x1):

```
[ 1.  1.  7. ...,  2.  1.  2.]
```

And my objective function to be maximised which is a vector of ones (1359,1).

Now in other packages my maximised objective function is 841, however using linprog:

```
res = linprog(c=OBJ_N, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, options={"disp": True})
```

It optimised successfully to -0.0 so I wonder if I'm using the right command in python and have my constraints the right way around?

**Edit**: Ok that makes sense, it was trying to minimise. I have rewritten now (swapped c and b and transposed A to minimise).

```
# (max t(C)*x s.t. Ax <=b) = min t(b)*x s.t. ATy = c, y ≥ 0
# (i): minimise number of shops no bounds
ID = np.ones(len(w[0]))
print(ID)
print(ID.shape)  #1359

At = A.transpose()

need_divest = (A.dot(ID)) - 1
print(need_divest)
print(need_divest.shape)  #1448

res = linprog(c=need_divest, A_eq=At, b_eq=ID, options={"disp": True})
print(res)
```

However, I get "message: 'Optimzation failed. Unable to find a feasible starting point.'"

Comment: linprog: `Minimize a linear objective function subject to linear equality and inequality constraints.` - Does that help?

Comment: You are going the wrong way... Here you are trying to solve the `dual` problem of your original `minimization` problem.
You can consider the answer below to state correctly your original problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are probably `minimizing` instead of `maximizing` your objective function.
Try with this (inserting a **-** in front of your objective function coefficients) :

```
res = linprog(c=-OBJ_N, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, options={"disp": True})
```

Your result should then be -841.

This works simply because :

```
min(f(x))=-max(-f(x))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You cured my long hour of stupidity

Comment: Nothing to do with stupidity, you just needed a small refreshment in linear programming :)

Comment: I don't think you can do that using `linprog`. Problem is much more difficult when you need integral variables so there are different resolution algorithms for those `ILP`problems. Have a look at this if you want to know more on where to look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305704/python-mixed-integer-linear-programming

Comment: Interestingly when I imposed the constraint that x is between 0 and 1 (res = linprog(c=-ID, A_ub=A, b_ub=need_sell, bounds=(0,1), options={"disp": True})) I was able to match my answer using the R package. So I wonder if it's the case it forces an integer? However, I guess it could be a coincidence. Thank you for the link!

Comment: No, just a coïncidence (lucky you !) I guess. It may happen depending of the structure of your problem. But they say in the documentation that only the `simplex` algorithm is implemented yet, and it cannot solve ILP (else we'll be rich because we would have proven a famous mathematical conjecture that is P=NP !).