# Binary constraint in scipy linprog

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-programming

I have a system of linear inequalities, and I want to solve it using scipy.optomize.linprog. It's code where I call linprog function:

```
res = linprog(c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, A_eq=A_eq, b_eq=b_eq, bounds=(0, 1), options={"disp": True})
```

It's work fine and It's solve my system, but I want that x[i] can be only 0 or 1(no fractional). It's possible to do this?

```
[0.0, 2.1239049166742128e-16, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5217391304347825, 1.0, 
0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.47826086956521746, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,0.0]
```

Comment: You mean you want all positive values to be = 1?

Comment: I mean all values must be integer(no fractional)

Comment: so does `res.astype(int)` work?

Comment: no, it throw AttributeError: astype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linprog is an LP solver and assumes all variables are continuous. What you are looking for is a Mixed Integer Programming solver. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305704/python-mixed-integer-linear-programming) for some suggestions for calling MIP solvers from Python.