# Linear optimizations model with specified types for variable

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, lpsolve

Is there any implementation of linear optimization model in python which allows explicitly define the types of my variables. For example I want my variable to be only integers. I can define this when using lpSolve in R like:

```
    set.type(model, 1:18,type = "integer")
```

but I need to build linear optimization model in python.

There is a scipy's linprog implementation but it doesn't allow to define the type of my variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since IP (Integer Programming) and LP (Linear Programming) are solved with very different algorithms it's legitimate that some solvers don't allow to mix both (IMO): IP has an exponential complexity and LP a polynomial complexity. Your problem is a MILP (Mixed Integer Linear Programming) which has thus an exponential complexity, so you need a [MILP solver for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305704/python-mixed-integer-linear-programming). But be aware that if you introduce many integer variables even small problem instances might become very hard to solve. Scipy's linprog is just a LP solver according to the documentation.

And by the way it looks like there is also a [python interface to lpsolve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/Python.htm), and another interface [pylpsolve](http://www.stat.washington.edu/~hoytak/code/pylpsolve/) that looks more up to date. I gave pylpsolve a try, and was able to clone from the github repo and install it, you might take a look at this function (according to what I told earlier, you will notice that the names are confusing...)

```
>>> from pylpsolve import LP
>>> help(LP.setInteger)
```