# Solving system of linear equations with variables taking binary values

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, pulp, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to solve a system of linear equations where the variables take binary values

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as LA
import scipy.optimize as optimize

A = np.array([[1/5, 1/2, 1/3], [1/4, 1/5, 1/6], [1/6, 2/9, 3/10]])
b = np.array([1, 1, 1])
x = LA.solve(A, b)
```

My matrix A has around 400 columns and 3000 rows. Just posted few columns due to space constraint. My output vector is always 1. All my variables can take only binary values - 0 or 1

Comment: I cant get your code to work, I get the following error **LinAlgError: Singular matrix**

Comment: Maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26305704/8069403) could be usefull, about Mixed Integer Linear Programming. Another keyword seem to be 'system of boolean equations' instead of binary equations ([for example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2103949))

Comment: Thankyou @xdze2, that helped. However I am stuck at formulating optimizing the squares function using Pulp

Comment: Are you even sure your linear system has at least one solution over the reals? This looks like a least-squares problem to me.