# Combinatorial constraint satisfaction and optimization

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, sat, mixed-integer-programming

## Problem

I created a set of polygons based on bag of plane intersection.

[image: schermafbeelding 2018-10-11 om 16 50 39]

Now I try to create the following manifold by combinatorial optimization.

[image: schermafbeelding 2018-10-11 om 16 50 51]

- *Manifold constraint* each edge in the final model should be incident to two polygons.
- *Optimize weight* each polygon has a confidence weight, the model should optimize towards highest overal confidence
- *Optimize simplicity* Optimize towards less corners (more polygons in the same plane)

## Attempt

The idea was to use `python-constraint` to generate possible solutions and select the best fitting by optimization of some weights on each polygon with `scipy.optimize`.

However, tried the following with `python-constraint` and it is not able to generate solutions.

```
import constraint
problem = constraint.Problem()
problem.addVariables(range(len(polygons)), [True, False])

for idx, polygon in enumerate(polygons):
    edge_adjacent_polygons = [polygon[a][b]['polygon'] for a, b in polygon.edges()]
    if all([len(adjacent_polygons) > 2 for adjacent_polygons in edge_adjacent_polygons]):
        for adjacent_polygons in edge_adjacent_polygons:
            problem.addConstraint(lambda *adjacent_polygons: sum(adjacent_polygons) == 2, adjacent_polygons)
    elif any([len(adjacent_polygons) == 2 for adjacent_polygons in edge_adjacent_polygons]) & \
        all([len(adjacent_polygons) >= 2 for adjacent_polygons in edge_adjacent_polygons]):
        problem.addConstraint(lambda idx: idx == True, [idx])
    else:
        problem.addConstraint(lambda idx: idx == False, [idx])
```

Other ideas I had were to model this as a graph optimization problem in NetworkX and using something like `min_weighted_vertex_cover`. Or using the jMetalPy library, however it is unclear to me how to model this problem in these approaches.

## Question

I understand this problem combines non-linear optimization and a combinatorial satisfaction problem. My most important questions are;

- is my approach correct or overcomplicated?
- does a tool exist to model such a problem?

The original problem (and images) are from a paper I try to replicate https://repository.kaust.edu.sa/handle/10754/627151. In the paper the proprietary Gurobi solver is used. I cannot use this solver due to license.

Comment: Reading this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26314315/4925208, makes me feel like there exists no open source python MINLP solver.

Comment: The paper states that they are using a plain linear MIP model (solved with Gurobi). In that case you don't need any MINLP functionality.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen thanks for correcting me there, that should make the search easier. Do you have suggestions for this problem?

Comment: I would try to organize things such that it is easy to use different solvers. The performance of different MIP solvers on the same model can differ dramatically.