# Given a table of letter counts and a list of words, find N words using all the letters

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am looking for an efficient algorithm to do the following.

Given a table/dictionary of letter counts

```
counts = {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 2, 'e': 2, 'k':2, 'r': 2 }
```

and a list of M words

```
words = ['break, 'add', 'build' ... ]
```

write a function that finds N words using all the letters (and words from the list)

```
>>> find_words(counts, words, 3)
['break', 'break', 'add']
```

The naive approach of going over all the words N times is too slow (I think it's O(m^n)).

Comment: You used `break` twice but appears only once in the word list. Is it ok? Also, please give that complete word list of words.

Comment: yes it can contain the same word multiple times. The list of words doesn't matter it can be anything

Comment: ok, is it fine if the count of any individual character is more than what is there in `counts`? For example- let's say `break` was `brrreeaak`. As you can see, `r` is `2` in `counts` but is `3` in `brrreeaak`.

Comment: no the total of all the letters of the N output words must sum to the `counts`. `brrreeaak` would be invalid as this word itself has 3 Rs while you need the sum of the Rs in all 3 words to be 2.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has a strongly NP-complete feeling to it.  I therefore would expect there to be no truly efficient solution.

I would therefore suggest that you try reducing it to a known problem and solve that instead.  In particular you can convert this to an integer linear programming problem.  Solvers for those are often surprisingly good.  And per [Python Mixed Integer Linear Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305704/python-mixed-integer-linear-programming) there are a number that are available to you relatively easily.

The specific problem that you are trying to solve is this.  You are trying to find a vector of `m` integers `x_i` such that `0 ≤ x_i`, `sum(x_i) ≤ n`, and for each letter `l`, the sum of how many times the letter has been used does not exceed your count.  The objective function that you would like to maximize is the sum of `x_i * (1 + len(w_i))` where `w_i` is the `i`'th word.

This will always produce an answer.  The answer that you get will represent a solution to your problem if and only if the objective function is `n` plus the count of letters available.  If the objective function is less than that, then no solution exists.