# Trouble with installing MIPCL-PY open source optimization-solver for python

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I'm trying to follow the instructions to install the MIPCL-PY API of the MIPCL solver (https://github.com/onebitbrain/MIPCL/tree/master/mipcl_py), about which I've heard it is a good open-source alternative to the python-API of CPLEX. My first question would be if it is possible to install it on a Mac (2017, Mojave) using the Linux-Download, and also what's supposed to happen after entering the "ln -s mipcl-py3.so mipcl.so" command in the terminal, as I only get the output "ln: mipcl.so: File exists". Or should I maybe follow the instructions from the general README, since now I follow the instructions from the mipcl-py folder? Also, in case it doesn't work on Mac, would it work on Ubuntu on a virtual box? Thanks for any hints or maybe even an explanation for starters, since the instructions to install MIPCL leave me quite lost, without even really knowing what the objective of the instructions is.

Comment: It didn't work for me on a mac -- I just got weird errors when trying to load mipcl.so. Ubuntu seems like a better bet (I did not try). If you're trying to play with different open-source MIP solvers in python, then make sure to check out the pulp package, which by default uses the CBC solver for MIPs. It is much easier to setup (`pip install pulp`) and has great documentation.

Comment: If this was really an open-source solver, you would be able to recompile. However,  AFAIK there is no source code available, so this is not possible.